# Pass parameter from one function to other function in the same Controller Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have two functions in the same controller. How can i pass $id from search($id) function to searchcond() function.

My First function:

```
public function search($id)
{
    return view('frontend.studentinfoajax', compact('data_dep', 'data_branch_dep'));

}
```

My Second Function:

```
public function searchcond()
{                          
    return DB::table('studentinfo')
                ->where('branchID', '=', $id)
                ->orderby('fullname')
                ->get();
}
```

How can i pass $id from search($id) function to searchcond() function.

Comment: $this->searchcond($id);

Comment: @Bugfixer Where can i put these??

Comment: in your first function

Comment: @Bugfixer how can i write where in my second function?

Comment: if ur second function is in same class use $this. Use Request $request as parameter for ur 1st function then get ur id and pass to second function.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know why you need like that but still if you need you can use class properties

```
private $id; //define property to the class

public function search($id)
{
    $this->id=$id;
    return view('frontend.studentinfoajax', 
                compact('data_dep', 
                'data_branch_dep'));

}


public function searchcond()
{            
    $id=$this->id;              
    return DB::table('studentinfo')
                ->where('branchID', '=', $test)
                ->orderby('fullname')
                ->get();
}
```

Comment: can't pass parameter $id

Comment: $this->id will have parameter $id value

Comment: But still can'get value of $id

Answer (score 1):

After seeing the code snippets you have provided what i understood that you want to acheive something like this :

```
public function search($id)
{
    $data = $this->searchcond($id);
    return view('frontend.studentinfoajax', compact('data_dep', 'data_branch_dep'));

}
private function searchcond($id)
{       

    return DB::table('studentinfo')
                ->where('branchID', '=', $id)
                ->orderby('fullname')
                ->get();
}
```

Comment: Still can't pass $id to second function

Comment: is the $id the branchID that you need to pass for the query

Comment: I have a similar case and it got corrected by using like this in a controller: private function notifyPayment($txn,$response)
    {
        $membership_transaction = MembershipTransaction::where('transaction_no',$txn)->first();
        $membership_transaction->payment_gateway_response = $response;
        $membership_transaction->save();
    }